# Remove default delay before second launch of ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation, horizontalscrollview, objectanimator

I'm scrolling `HorizontalScrollView` using `ObjectAnimator` (left -> right -> left). Therefore the result should be kind of infinite scrolling from one side to another.

The **problem** is that there's some delay like 1 sec after I start to animate right -> left. What causes such behavior?

I've created 2 animations and start one after another (*if you know better solution that's appreciated*):

```
final ObjectAnimator animRight = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hScrollView, "scrollX", hScrollView.getRight());
animRight.setDuration(SCROLL_DURATION);

final ObjectAnimator animLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hScrollView, "scrollX", 0);
animLeft.setDuration(SCROLL_DURATION);

animRight.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        animLeft.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

    @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
 });

 animLeft.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
         animRight.start(); //delay occurs here
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
 });

 animRight.start();
```

Comment: see the docs of `ObjectAnimator` ^F repeat

Comment: Yea, I know about repeat. But there's a problem to build full path to animation i.e. right-left-right so it should be smooth

Comment: just use right interpolator, like `CycleInterpolator`

Comment: could you please provide a sample? That would be very kind of you

Comment: a sample of what? how to call `setInterpolator(TimeInterpolator value)`?

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried applying a Linear Interpolator to your animations?

The default interpolator is not linear so could be responsible for the delay. To apply it:

```
animRight.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animLeft.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Comment: Applied. Scroll became not accelerated as was before but the delay still exists